# Pass system variables to the application deployed to tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I do have a tomcat server where three apps are running. 
For one of them i need to pass the system variables (-D) like spring active profiles and some other project specific variables. 
I've read the documentation and one of the solutions was to create a context.xml (as far as i understood it has to have the same name as the war file) at $CATALINA_BASE/localhost/ folder

I've tried to do it like that

```py
<Context>
  <Parameter name="spring.profiles.active" value="profile"
  override="false"/>
        <Parameter name="variable" value="value"
  override="false"/>
</Context>
```

But after the tomcat is restarted seems that the app is not starting and nothing actually happens.

Since there are 3 apps on tomcat server i'm unable to use setenv.sh and the parameters have to be passed specifically for this project.

Do you have any idea on what am i doing wrong and how to pass the system variables to a specific application on tomcat server?

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that i've named the file context.xml and not the applicationName.xml
The file itself looks like:

```
<Context>
<Environment name="spring.profiles.active" value="profile" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
```